# C++ Hash Table Seg Fault (Pointer Allocation)

Tags: c++

I am trying to implement a Hash Table using Linear Probing. However, in my search function, a seg fault is occurring, and I am unsure why. It seems to be to do with how I am initialising the Hash Table within the class definition - I do not think it is liking the `table[i] = new HashNode()` part, although I know everything is being created due to having couts there previously.

The Search function is part of my Insert function. I have already checked that my HashFunction function (assigns an index to a word) is working correctly.

My HashNode class is declared as follows:

```
class HashNode{
public:
string word ;
string status ;

// Basic constructor for a node
HashNode(string word, string status) {
    // this keyword references the key and word variables which belong to the class
    this->word = word ;
    this->status = status ;
}
} ;
```

My HashTable class is declared as follows:

```
class HashTable{
private:
// Contains an array of pointers to items
HashNode **table ;  // 2D array
static const int TableSlots = 26 ;  // size of alphabet
int size ;  // current size
// Create tombstone node
HashNode *tombstone ;
public:
// Initialise constructor
HashTable(){
    size = 0 ;
    HashNode **table = new (HashNode*)[TableSlots] ;

    // Initialise all elements of array to "never used", aka. NULL
    for (int i = 0; i < TableSlots; i++){
        // Allocate pointer to a singular node (2nd dimension of 2D array)
        // Only one node as no chaining is required
        table[i] = new HashNode("NULL", "never used") ; // deference pointer
        cout << "hash node status: " << table[i]->status << endl ;
        cout << "hash node word: " << table[i]->word << endl ;
    }

    // Initialise tombstone node
    tombstone = new HashNode("NULL","tombstone") ;

    cout << "created hash table" << endl ;
}
// Hashing function: takes a key, returns integer
int hashFunction(string word) ;
// Search function (returns true/false)
bool Search(string word) ;
// Helper function (provides index)
int SearchSlot(string word) ;
// Insert function
void Insert(string word) ;
// Delete function
void deleteNode(string word) ;
// Print function
void printNode() ;
} ;
```

My hash function:

```
// Function assumes the key is valid and not empty
int HashTable::hashFunction(string word){

cout << "hash function implemented" << endl ;
cout << "word passed to function: " ;
for (int i = 0; i < word.size(); i++) cout << word[i] ;
    cout << endl ;

char lastChar = word[word.size()-1] ;

// Initialise return variable
int slot_num ;

// There are 26 different lists (array indexes include 0-25)
// a->0, b->1, etc.
if (lastChar == 'a') slot_num = 0 ;
else if (lastChar == 'b') slot_num = 1 ; 
else if (lastChar == 'c') slot_num = 2 ; 
else if (lastChar == 'd') slot_num = 3 ; 
else if (lastChar == 'e') slot_num = 4 ; 
else if (lastChar == 'f') slot_num = 5 ; 
else if (lastChar == 'g') slot_num = 6 ; 
else if (lastChar == 'h') slot_num = 7 ; 
else if (lastChar == 'i') slot_num = 8 ; 
else if (lastChar == 'j') slot_num = 9 ; 
else if (lastChar == 'k') slot_num = 10 ; 
else if (lastChar == 'l') slot_num = 11 ; 
else if (lastChar == 'm') slot_num = 12 ; 
else if (lastChar == 'n') slot_num = 13 ; 
else if (lastChar == 'o') slot_num = 14 ; 
else if (lastChar == 'p') slot_num = 15 ; 
else if (lastChar == 'q') slot_num = 16 ; 
else if (lastChar == 'r') slot_num = 17 ; 
else if (lastChar == 's') slot_num = 18 ; 
else if (lastChar == 't') slot_num = 19 ; 
else if (lastChar == 'u') slot_num = 20 ; 
else if (lastChar == 'v') slot_num = 21 ; 
else if (lastChar == 'w') slot_num = 22 ; 
else if (lastChar == 'x') slot_num = 23 ; 
else if (lastChar == 'y') slot_num = 24 ;
else if (lastChar == 'z') slot_num = 25 ;  

return slot_num % TableSlots ;
}
```

My Search function:

```
bool HashTable::Search(string word){

cout << "search function called" << endl ;

// Get first possible index for given word
int slot = hashFunction(word) ;

cout << "table size:" << table.size() << endl ;
//table[slot]->word = word ;
cout << "slot num from search function: " << slot << endl ; 
// SEG FAULTS HERE //
cout << "table slot 0" << table[slot]->word << endl ;

cout << "table slot status" << table[slot]->status << endl ;

/*
Each letter has its own key, but:
    a) may have multiple words which end with the same letter
    b) word may have moved index due to collision
    c) word may be placed after a "tombstone" slot
*/
while (table[slot]->status != "never used"){
    // if the node is found, return true
    //if ( strcmp(table[slot]->word, word) ) return true ;
    if(table[slot]->word == word) return true ;
    // increment index and wrap back around the table
    slot++ ;
    slot %= TableSlots ;
}

cout << "word not found, returning false" << endl ;

return false ;
}
```

My Insert function:

```
void HashTable::Insert(string word){

// Search to see if the node exists
bool exists = Search(word) ;
cout << "exists: " << exists << endl ;

if (exists == false){
    // Create a new node
    //HashNode *temp = new HashNode(word, "occupied") ;

    cout << "inserting" << endl ;

    int slot = hashFunction(word) ;

    while (table[slot]->status != "never used" && table[slot]- 
>status != "tombstone")
    {
        slot++ ;
        slot %= TableSlots ;
    }

    table[slot]->word = word ;
    table[slot]->status = "occupied" ;  // sets status to 
    // occupied by default
    size++ ;    // increase current size of occupied slots in 
    // hash table
}
}
```

My delete function:

```
void HashTable::deleteNode(string word){

// Search to see if the node exists
bool exists = Search(word) ;

if (exists == true){
    int slot = SearchSlot(word) ;   // get index of slot

    // Get temp pointer
    HashNode *temp = table[slot] ;

    // Set table slot to tombstone hashnode
    table[slot] = tombstone ;

    // Delete temp node
    delete(temp) ;

    // Decrement current size of occupied hash table slots
    size-- ;
}

}
```

My main function:

```
int main(){

string input ;
getline(cin, input) ;

size_t start = 0 ;
size_t space = input.find_first_of(" ") ;
string func ;   // to store first characters in, no bigger than 26
vector<string> filtered ;   // to store each word or 'key' in
unsigned int len = 0 ;  // substring length for filtered elements

while(space != string::npos){

    // If space > start, a word has been filtered - store as string element
    if (start == 0){
        len = space - start - 1 ;
        filtered.push_back(input.substr(start + 1, len)) ;
        func += input[start] ;
    }
    else if (start != 0){
        len = space - start - 2 ;
        filtered.push_back(input.substr(start + 2, len)) ;
        func += input[start + 1] ;
    }

    start = space++ ;
    space = input.find_first_of(" ", space) ;
}

// Add last word (cut off during while loop once string::npos is 
// reached)
func+= input[start + 1] ;
filtered.push_back(input.substr(start + 2)) ;

for (int i = 0; i < filtered.size(); i++) cout << filtered[i] << 
" " ;
    cout << endl ;

// Instantiate a new HashTable object
HashTable *hashT = new HashTable() ;

// Perform insertion/deletion
for (int i = 0; i < func.size(); i++){
    if (func[i] == 'A') hashT->Insert(filtered.at(i)) ;
    else if (func[i] == 'D') hashT->deleteNode(filtered.at(i)) ;
}

hashT->printNode() ;

return 0 ;
}
```

Apologies for all the couts, just trying to debug the code. I'm also relatively new to C++ so this is for learning and experimentation. Any other comments are welcome.

Comment: Your `Insert` function doesn't create a new node. So how is it supposed to work exactly? Also, what is supposed to happen if there's more than one entry in a slot? Where's the code to handle that or even some comments explaining what the code is supposed to do?

Comment: My Insert function effectively updates the existing Node's word and status when the table is initialised within the HashTable constructor, so it doesn't need to create any new nodes. The implementation is hashing by linear probing, so no chaining is implemented in the design (if the slot is occupied, it will use the search function to search for the next slot with either a "never used" or "tombstone" status to update.

Comment: That is not possible to determine from the code shown. We're going to need enough code to replicate the problem.

Comment: I will edit with the rest of my code.

Answer (score 0):

You could revise the code as below:

```
 table = new (HashNode*)[TableSlots] ;//could not be a temp pointer
```